# OR operator within Where clause is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, or-operator

I am doing an update using a where clause. Within the where clause I am using an OR condition to get both cases covered. Following is my code:

```
UPDATE 
    table1
SET
    id = table2.id
FROM table2
where (cast(table2.number as bigint) = table1.number) 
OR (table2.identifier = table1.identifier)
```

If I execute the update in 2 different update statements, it works. But if I try to do it using OR in the WHERE clause it keeps running forever. One thing that I should mention is I have multiple null values in both the tables for number field as well as for identifier field. But both of these cases cover the total ids that I need to update since the rows where identifier is null there is number available and rows where number is null, an identifier is available. Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: It very likely comes down to what indexes you have. As two separate statements, the SQL optimizer can devise two optimal access plans. As a single combined statement, it can't find a good access plan covering both, and is not allowed to treat them separately. --- How many records are in each of the two tables, and do you have indexes on `number` and `identifier` columns?

Comment: I created indexes with the following code :
```
CREATE INDEX test_index ON table2 (number, identifier)
```
around 3 million in both the tables

Comment: So no index on `number` or `identifier` columns?

Comment: I do have indexes on both the columns but only in table2 @Andreas

Comment: Does it make sense to create the indexes for number and identifier on table1 as well? @Andreas

Comment: Why the cast? Joining on columns that have different data types is a strong indication of a wrong data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in table2 the number is stored as type varchar but would it make a difference if i change the type to bigint ( same as table1 )? then both the data types would be identical. But does it have relevance in figuring out why the or statement is not working? Because even with the cast if i do the UPDATE in separate statements, it works

Comment: @Sam . . . I think you have separate indexes on `number` and `identifier` in `table1`.  In any case, you would have to look at the execution plans to see the difference.